# Android CookieManager setCookie adds new cookie instead of overwrites

Tags: android, cookies, http-headers

I have the following code:

```
   String cookieString = "sessionid=;";
    CookieManager c = CookieManager.getInstance();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        c.setCookie("https://my.url.com/someotherstuff", cookieString);
        Log.v("Cookies: ", c.getCookie("https://my.url.com/someotherstuff"));
    }
```

Instead of replacing "sessionid" cookie the output is as such:

```
Cookies:: sessionid=; sessionid=someIDNumber; csrftoken=someOtherIDNumber
```

So it is adding a new sessionid?

Anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue.  Did you ever find a solution for this?